# Best practices for dimensioning control panels in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I defined a Window in WPF, into this one I put a "stack panel" and inside this panel I put a "tab control" and some "button controls".

When executing the program, I would like that when I have to resize the window using the mouse, the stack panel and all controls inside it can also be resized automatically and proportionally to the window.

How can I get this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `StackPanel` only uses the space that its child controls need; it does *not* resize to the available space of the window.

If you want this behavior, use a different type of panel: If you only want the tab control to resize, use a `DockPanel` and make the tab control the last child of the DockPanel. A DockPanel stretches to the available space of the parent, with the last child getting all the space not used by the previous children.

```
<DockPanel>
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" />
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" />
    <TabControl>
        ...
    </TabControl>
</DockPanel>
```

If you need more complex spacing behavior (for example, you want the Buttons to proportionally take up more space as well), have a look at the `Grid` control.

Answer (score 0):

If you want everything to just scale up and down uniformly, so you might end up with giant or tiny controls and fonts, wrap the entire window contents (currently, the `StackPanel`) in a `Viewbox` control.

Comment: Jay, Visual Studio does not allow me to wrap the StackPanel in the ViewBox.

Comment: @vizcaynot In what way doesn't it allow you? `<Viewbox><StackPanel>...</StackPanel></Viewbox>` is perfectly valid XAML -- I just tried it in VS2008 SP1. Make sure you're not trying to wrap the `<Window>`.